# Regexp to find "E numbers" in ingredients-texts of food

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I'm working on a project for analyzing food products. Programming in VB.net, C# and using a MS SQL Server DB.

I now need to find every occurrence of "E numbers" in the ingredients-text-field. 
(E numbers is a European standard coding-system for food additives, se [Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_number)).

E numbers has this format(s):

1. The capital letter "E" (1 char).
2. An optional [space] (0 - 1 char).
3. A three or four digit number in the range 100 to 1600 (3 - 4 char).
4. A optional smallCAP letter in the range "a" to "f" (0 - 1 char).
   Making it a total of 4 to 7 characters length.

*The number is often enclosed in parentheses and/or immediately concatenated with a ingredient-name, then (possibly) not leaving any space or separator before or after it.

Examples: E100, Formaldehyde(E 240), E300b, E 1234a, (E1321).

I need to have returned all the E numbers (as the format above) that is in the text. There can be a lot of them.
Any ideas?

-Never got around to learning RegExp properly, hence the question.

Comment: You have described your requirements very clearly, but this is not a site for asking someone else to write code for you. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex pattern `E ?\d{3,4}[a-f]?`  See the [online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=E%20%3F%5Cd%7B3%2C4%7D%5Ba-f%5D%3F&i=E100%2C%20Formaldehyde(E%20240)%2C%20E300b%2C%20E%201234a%2C%20(E1321)).

- `E ?` - Must begin with an E followed by an optional space (the `?` makes the preceding space optional).
- `\d{3,4}` - The next three or four characters must be digits
- `[a-f]?` - The last character may optionally be any letter between *a* and *f*

You can search for all of the matches like this:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Comment: Great solution, clean and we'll explained Mr Doggart! This should be the accepted answer! Also nice catch on the accepted answer as it will fail as you mentioned.

Comment: Instead of an actual space I would use `\s`

Comment: @Jeroen I considered that, but that would match any white space character. Since the spec according to the OP was only a space (and not a tab or line feed or the like), I chose to go with the more strict requirement.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Fair enough! I am so used to specs saying `space` and finding all kinds of other non-printable stuff, I just gotten in the habit of using `\s`

Answer (score 0):

An expression that should work:

(E)+(\s+)?(\d{4}|\d{3})+([a-f])?

**Capture Group 0**: Makes sure there is at least 1 Capital E

**Capture Group 1**: As many spaces as possible if there are spaces

**Capture Group 2**: Either a 4 or 3 digit number

**Capture Group 3**: An optional letter between a and f.

Try this C# code.

```
using System;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 namespace myapp
{
   class Class1
     {
       static void Main(string[] args)
         {
           String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
           Regex re = new Regex(@"(E)(\s+)?(\d{4}|\d{3})+([a-f])?");
           MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
           int mIdx=0;
           foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
             for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
               {
                 Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
               }
             mIdx++;
           }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Works beautifully and fast!

Comment: The plus characters shouldn't be in there. For instance, the way your pattern currently is, it will match EE123123

Comment: Thank you Steven for you comment. You are right. I updated my RegEx to only match 1 E.